# How many ways can you add 3 non-negative integers so the sum is less than 10?

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways can you add 3 non-negative integers so the sum is less than 10?

Comment: Do you know how many ways you can add 3 non-negative integers so the sum is exactly 10?

Comment: As zero is allowed, suppressing it first count pairs like $8+1, 7+2, 6+3,5+4$ giving sum 9, then pairs summing to 8, $7+1,6+2,5+3,4+4$. and so on up to the last pair giving $2=1+1$. Then try triples giving sum 9: $4+4+1, 4+3+2$. You can finish off in 5 minutes.

Comment: @vadim123 yes, that'd be $C_{12}^9$.

Comment: As is the custom on here, we'll ask "What have you tried?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

You can think of the problem of summing three non-negative integers and getting $9$ or less as being the problem of summing four non-negative integers and getting exactly $9$, where the fourth number is your "left-overs".

Comment: Can I ask how to cancel the order of the solutions? e.g. How to make 1+2+1+0 and 2+1+1+0 the same in general?

Comment: If that is the problems intentions, there are a few ways to go about it.  A common way: instead of thinking about choosing numbers, think about choosing multiplicities.  In other words: choose how many $0$'s, how many $1$'s, etc. The multiplicities have to add up to $4$, and $\sum i\cdot\mu(i)$ (where $\mu(i)$ is the multiplicity of $i$) must add up to $9$.

Comment: @NickPeterson, Hi Nick I have been looking at this question and do not know how to proceed, am I right in that if 1+2+1+0 = 0, 2+1+1+0 are different, then there are 12C3 ways? I split 9 into 9 1s, and then the problem is converted to ordering groups of indistinguishable objects? and how do I go about changing it so 1+2+1+0 = 0, 2+1+1+0 are the same? and if problem excluded 0 would it be 8C3?